# Logback JsonLayout printing all logs on the same line

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

I am using JsonLayout with Spring Boot to log messages in JSON format. I only want the log messages to be logged to the console and not to a log file.

I notice that the JSON logs are logged continuously on the same line. On production this would be alright, since we would be shipping the logs to a log aggregator. But this becomes a bit difficult to analyze on local development.

**Logs**

```
{"timestamp":"2016-11-13 23:06:17.727","level":"INFO","thread":"qtp745835029-19","logger":"com.test.controller.TestController","message":"Info log:: printme 1","context":"default"}{"timestamp":"2016-11-13 23:06:17.727","level":"DEBUG","thread":"qtp745835029-19","logger":"com.test.controller.TestController","message":"Debug log:: printme","context":"default"}{"timestamp":"2016-11-13 23:06:17.727","level":"WARN","thread":"qtp745835029-19","logger":"com.test.controller.TestController","message":"Warn log:: printme","context":"default"}{"timestamp":"2016-11-13 23:06:17.727","level":"ERROR","thread":"qtp745835029-19","logger":"com.test.controller.TestController","message":"Error log:: printme","context":"default"}
```

Below is the logback configuration
**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
            <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something in the configuration so that they are logged on separate lines on the console.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 75):

You need to set `appendLineSeparator` option to `true` for `ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout`. Example of this:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter" />
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
        <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: This is the answer!  Not pretty print.  You can still use pretty print, but it won't fix the issue because writes `} {` at the end of each message without appendSeparator=true.

Comment: What dependencies are need for this solution to work?

Answer (score 7):

Setting prettyPrint true is one solution. But there are cases where we need logs in single line like for sreaming to services like cloud watch.
Add following in layout

```
<appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
```

Answer (score 3):

The above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636222/2933389) from [@mvnm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307295/mvmn) worked fine for me. Just in case, if required pretty print and new line separator, can use the following configuration.

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
            <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
        </jsonFormatter>
        <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
        <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: For production pretty print not recommended to reduce space consumption. In case of local development, useful for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to using [logstah-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) which did not have the issue as JSONLayout.

Comment: Here's a good how to for setting up logstash-logback-encoder for Spring Boot: http://development.wombatsecurity.com/development/2017/09/29/logging-for-splunk-with-slf4j/

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of your Spring Boot application (or JSON log files) to [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) using something like this:

```
java -jar target/myapp.jar | jq -R 'fromjson?'
```

This will provide nice, color-highlighted, pretty-printed json that follows the output of your application. Anything output by your application that isn't JSON will be ignored (for example: the Spring Boot banner).

You can use filters in jq to display only the INFO level message output:

```
java -jar target/myapp.jar | jq -c -R 'fromjson? | select(.level="INFO") | {message}'
```

Or you can use filters to remove keys you don't want to see:

```
java -jar target/myapp.jar | jq -c -R 'fromjson? | del(.timestamp,.thread)'
```

Answer (score -3):

Editted : Try changing the prettyPrint to true -> `<prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>`

You re writing the logs twice in the `consoleAppender`

```
   <logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
```

change to

```
<logger name="jsonLogger" additivity="false" level="DEBUG"/>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar for your response. But removing the appender do not solve the issue of the logs being printed on the same line.

Comment: Try changing the prettyPrint to true -> <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>

Comment: Refer the documentation : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/JsonLayout.html , Probably you need to add complete = "true" in the <layout>

Comment: The JSONLayout class in logback doesnt have any such option.

Comment: You gave a link to Log4J documentation, but the question is about Logback, not Log4J.